# How can I efficiently compare multiple documents stored in a database using OpenAI chat completions API and select the best candidate?

Tags: plugins, chatbot, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have 5 to 6 Documents file and it is stored in database. I have created a chatbot and use Open AI chat completions APIs.

Now, I have to select only one document according to question but I have to pass all documents to Open AI chat completions API and because of tokens limitations i don't pass all documents.

So, there is any way to do check all documents and give best out of them using Any API or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting documents to embeddings and later upload them into a vector database. this will save good amount of tokens and will provide answers from a relevant document.